# Custom UITableCell Text Label wrong position after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom table view cell, with an additional <del>text field</del> text view.
I've added in autolayout constraints.  The cell's text label layout seems to be fine in portrait mode, but when rotated, the text label moves to the center of the cell(behind the text view), it is until I tap and type into the text view, the label gets adjusted to the right location.

.h

```
@interface MTTextViewCell : UITableViewCell

- (id)initWithLabelTextForView:(NSString *)labelTextForView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *cellTextView;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "MTTextViewCell.h"

@implementation MTTextViewCell

- (id)initWithLabelTextForView:(NSString *)labelTextForView {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        //1.    Setup existing cell elements.
        self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.textLabel.text = labelTextForView;
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        //2.    Setup custom cell elements.
        _cellTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        _cellTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _cellTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:_cellTextView];
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

        //Local variables for the purposes of autolayout language and macros.
        UIView *alTextLabel = self.textLabel;
        UIView *alCellTextView = _cellTextView;
        NSDictionary *alViewDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(alTextLabel, alCellTextView);

        //Horizontal layout constraints.
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[alCellTextView]-|"
                                                                                options:0
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:alViewDictionary]];
        //Vertical layout constraints.
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[alTextLabel(20.0)]-[alCellTextView]-|"
                                                                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:alViewDictionary]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

This also sporadically happens to a similar cell using a text field, as 
well as a segmented control.
See screencap:

[image: screenshot showing wrong position of text label]

I am on Xcode Version 6.4, iOS SDK 8.4
Any suggestions or pointers is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check that the heights add up to the maximum height of the phone in landscape mode. It's probably adding to greater than the height now

Comment: Hi Jaimy, I don't do anything special with the height - for the enclosing table view controller, currently I have the height to return the same for all cells, see portions of the view controller below:

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return 160.0f;
 }

Comment: did you set a vertical constraint between the "Segmented control" text label and the abc boxes? you do it by ctrl + dragging from the text label to the abc box. you should also pin the top and leading edges of the text label to the cell

Comment: The abc boxes are actually the segmented controls - they look that way because i've set the row height at the table view controller level to test out the auto layout.  I'll go back to my post and post more of the related source code - which can better explain the situation.